# How to access a json file that is inside an internal framework in Swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, bundle

Code to find my framework location

```
//  Bundle+Ext.swift
//  AVStream
private final class AVStream { }

extension Bundle {
    static var avstream: Bundle {
        moduleBundle(for: AVStream.self)
    }
    public static func moduleBundle(for object: AnyObject) -> Bundle! {
        Bundle.moduleBundle(forObject: object)
    }

    public static func moduleBundle(forObject: AnyObject) -> Bundle {
        Bundle(for: type(of: forObject))
    }
}
```

A tried to get the url, but it is nil

```
guard let url = Bundle.avstream.url(forResource:"RemoteVideos", withExtension: "json") else {
    return
}
```

[my framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYbQH.png)

Comment: Have you checked if your resource file is correctly embedded in your compiled framework? Is it in a sub-directory? In that case you may use `url(forResource:withExtension:subdirectory:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1416712-url

Comment: The json file was not added to the framework Target Membership on the Xcode
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654599

Answer (score 1):

After adding the file to the framework on the Target Membership. I was able to get the file's path/url[image]